# Get Stream Chat: Is it possible to hide message from the customers?

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

I'd like to add messages that are visible only to our support team, but should be hidden on the customer side.

The opposite should also be possible, how can I send a message from the backend straight to the customer but hide it for our support team?

Tried to search about SYSTEM messages but didn't find anything usable.